# File.Exists() file not found after impersonate

Tags: c#, webforms

Firstable, I am in WebForms ASP.NET.

In a method I wrote,

```
        string source = Global.PathTempFile + fileNamePosted + ".htm";
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using(StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                w.WriteLine(Request.Form["hide_redige"]);
            }
        }
        bool exist = File.Exists(source); // true here (for test)

        new MoveFile(source, Global.HADmdcdc + "\\" + fileNamePosted + ".htm", true);
```

This code create a new file in my temporary folder,
at this moment, the file is recognized by File.Exists()

But, for security reason, I created a class to manipulate the file as a particular User (which has rights to write in target folder)

```
    public MoveFile(string sourcePath, string targetPath, bool isImpersonate)
    {
        if (isImpersonate)
            moveImp(sourcePath, targetPath);
        else
            move(sourcePath, targetPath);
    }
    private void moveImp(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
    {
        if (imp.impersonateValidUser(id["domain"], id["login"], id["password"]))
            move(sourcePath, targetPath);

        imp.undoImpersonation();
    }
    private void move(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
    {
        if (File.Exists(sourcePath)) // false here
        {
            if (File.Exists(targetPath))
                File.Delete(targetPath);

            File.Move(sourcePath, targetPath);
        }
    }
```

So, my question is, why the test of File.Exists() return a different value? 
Also, i'm sure that the file exists.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266637/why-does-system-io-file-existsstring-path-return-false ?

Comment: no, but I think, this is not really the same case. In my case I got a true return with the first part of my code then a false return on same execution form my second part of code. 
the user is fully permission on all folders @DmitryBLR

Comment: Maybe the problem is with how you implemented impersonation? Have a look here if you spot something: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950106/move-a-file-with-impersonateloggedonuser

Comment: thanks for reply, the class that allows me to connect to the impersonate is like the one found in the link, other actions work very well with this class.
the error returned is the file is not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file exists this sounds like permission issue.

You need to check permissions of your `Application pool`

To find your `Application pool` name :

[image]

[image]

Now when you found your `Application pool`
open it :

[image]

Chenge it's itentity:

[image]
[image]

Choose custom account :

[image]

Set a user that can access to your file's directory